# Difference between actor and final actor

Tags: swift

So as in topic, my question is regarding actors in Swift and difference between declaring actor as final and none.

I couldn't find any information regarding that, it is some kind of oversight from an Apple? Or there is really some kind of difference between these declaraions?

Here's example of code.

```
actor MyActor { }

actor SubActor: MyActor { }
```

Of course I'm getting error `Actor types do not support inheritance`.

And if I change declaration of MyActor to final

```
final actor MyActor { }
```

There is another error `Inheritance from a final class 'MyActor'`

So I can only assume that underneath actor is an class and they forcibly disabled inheritance and they forgot to remove `final` word for actors.

Comment: Do you mean you change declaration to `final actor MyActor` _and_ define `actor SubActor: MyActor`? that's invalid for classes either: you can't inherit from final. So I am not sure where do you perceive the mistake? And the fact that actors do not support inheritance is part of the spec as of now, although they allowed this to change in the future (see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#actor-inheritance)

Comment: The change of MyActor to final, only was to show there's some kind of error related to classes, but not with my question, which is why there is option for marking actor as final if there is no difference between actor and final actor / or what is the difference between final actor and actor.